# How to customise or add a common header and footer to a report in odoo 12?

Tags: xml, report, qweb, odoo-12

How to customise or add a common header and footer to a report in odoo 12? I have found four types of report layout(background, boxed, clean and standard). But I am not able to add a header and footer. Is there any way to add a common header and footer for all reports in odoo version 12?

Comment: You need to override the original header and/or footer at https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/web/views/report_templates.xml

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit default layouts and modify them according to your requirement

```
<template id="web_external_layout_iherited" 
          inherit_id="web.external_layout_standard" customize_show="True" 
          name="Automatic Header">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='header']" position="replace">
    </xpath>
</template>
```